# Is there an easy way to solve a system of linear equations over Z/2Z in Python?

Tags: python-3.x, math, matrix

I'm practicing programming and I would like to know what is the easiest way to solve linear system of equations over the field Z/2Z? I found a problem where I managed to reduce the problem to solve a system of about 2200 linear equations over Z/2Z but I'm not sure what is the easiest way to write a solver for the equations. Is there simpler solution that use nested lists to represent a matrix and then manually write the Gauss–Jordan algorithm?

Comment: I think numpy is probably your best bet.  Does [this](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.solve.html) look like what you're looking for?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh Might be. Does it work over the finite field of two elements?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I don't think NumPy does linear algebra over finite fields.

Comment: If your matrix of coefficients is invertible, it looks like you're in luck: http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html?highlight=inv_mod#sympy.matrices.matrices.MatrixBase.inv_mod

Comment: Maybe sage then? http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/tour.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use Sage if this were a quick hack, and maybe consider using something optimized for GF(2) if the matrices are really big, to ensure that only one bit is used for each entry and that addition of several elements can be accomplished using a single XOR operation. One benefit of working over a finite field is that you don't have to worry about numeric stability, so naive Gauss–Jordan would sound like a good approach.